# Dividing 1.0 into three random proportions in Python

Tags: python-3.x

How can I divide 1.0 into three random proportions in Python? Below is an expected output.

```
Iteration 0:

Output: 0.5, 0.25, 0.25

Iteration 1:

Output: 0.4, 0.35, 0.25

Iteration 2:

Output: 0.2, 0.25, 0.55

...
```

Comment: Generate three random numbers (let's say, positive), then divide each by the product of the three.

Comment: What have you tried? Are you aware of the `random` module? If you've tried something, and can't make it work, please post a [MCVE]; we're not here to write your code for you, but we're happy to assist when you encounter problems.

Answer (score 0):

Generate two random integers in `[0, 1]`, e.g. with `random.random()`. Sort them in ascending order and call them `a < b`. Then your proportions will be `a, b-a, 1-b`.

Comment: Random integers between [0, 1] or fractions? It would be helpful if you could accompany a minimal snippet to support the idea.